# Agenda Telefonica

Tags: c++, linux

estoy escribiendo una agenda telefonica en C++ usando struct. El problema es que, por alguna razon, cuando quiero ingresar los valores de los distintos campos, hay uno que se salta, y no me permite ingresarlo.

La idea es esta: Una agenda de (por ahora) 4 contactos, con campos a rellenar. Cuando lleno los campos del primer contacto esta perfecto, pero cuando toca completar los campos del segundo, se saltea el campo correspondiente al nombre y pasa derecho al apellido. Dejo el codigo abajo.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;
struct agenda_telefonica{
    char nombre[30];
    char apellido[30];
    int prefijo;
    int telefono;
    } 
    contacto[4];
    
    int main(){
        int i;
        cout<<"\t\t\t***Agenda Telefonica***"<<endl;
        for(i=0;i<4;i++){
            cout<<"Ingrese su nombre: ";
            cin.getline(contacto[i].nombre,30,'\n');
            cout<<"ingrese su apellido: ";
            cin.getline(contacto[i].apellido,30,'\n');
            cout<<"Ingrese el prefijo: ";
            cin>>contacto[i].prefijo;
            cout<<"Ingrese su telefono: ";
            cin>>contacto[i].telefono;
        }
        for(i=0;i<4;i++){
            cout<<"Contacto "<<i+1<<": "<<endl;
            cout<<contacto[i].nombre<<" "<<contacto[i].apellido<<"\n";
            cout<<contacto[i].prefijo<<"-"<<contacto[i].telefono<<endl;
        }
       return 0; 
    }
```

Gracias por la ayuda!!!

Comment: Saludos, prueba de poner el segundo bucle de Contacto dentro del primer bucle. I la libreria string.h no deveria ser sin .h en C++?

Comment: Gracias por responder. Al final puse un fflush(stdin) al comienzo del primer for para vaciar el buffer y poder ingresar los datos nuevamente. Y si, la libreria deberia ser string, pero string.h tambien funciona en c++. Un saludo!!!

Answer (score 4):

Ya solucione. Como estoy usando Linux, la función ffflush(stdin) no funcionaba. Asi que utilice cin.ignore(256,'\n') al final del primer for, para que los datos almacenados se limpien y pueda ingresar nuevos a continuación.

Answer (score 3):

El problema es que

```
cin>>contacto[i].telefono;
```

lee el buffer de entrada buscando un entero. Un entero puede estar rodeado de *whitespace*. En este caso, cuando ingresas un teléfono por teclado, el último caracter ingresado es "\n", que marca el final del número.

Lo importante es que la lectura del entero no consume el *whitespace* que indica el fin del string.

Entonces, en la siguiente iteración, vas a leer el nombre:

```
cin.getline(contacto[i].nombre,30,'\n');
```

y en el buffer de entrada hay un "\n", por lo que `getline` retorna un string de largo cero.

**Solución**

Asegurarse de consumir el "\n" con que termina el número telefónico:

```
cout<<"Ingrese su telefono: ";
cin>>contacto[i].telefono;
char resto[80];
cin.getline(resto, 80, '\n');
```

Comment: Gracias!!!! Siempre sirven otras formas de solucionarlo, y la explicación fue genial.